# Reference request: Has those type-level tuples working in presence of Ur-elements, been defined before?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

Working in $\sf ZFA$, or in $\sf NFU$:

We split the universe $V$ into two **disjoint** subclasses $\mathcal V_1, \mathcal V_2$ that are equinumerous with $V$

Now we take two bijections:

$F_1:  V \to P^+(\mathcal V_1)  \\ F_2: V \to P^+(\mathcal V_2)$

, where: $P^+(X)=\{y \subseteq X \mid y \in V \land  \exists z : z \in y \}$

Now we define a type-level ordered pair, simply as: $$(a,b) = F_1(a) \cup F_2(b)$$

Retrieving projections is easy, to get the first projection simply intersect $(a,b)$ with $\mathcal V_1$, then apply $F_1^{-1}$; to get the second projection simply intersect $(a,b)$ with $\mathcal V_2$, then apply $F_2^{-1}$. In nutshell:

***Define:*** $\operatorname {Pair}(p) \iff  \exists a \exists b: p=F_1(a) \cup F_2(b)   $

$ \begin{align}   \operatorname {Pair}(p) \to & \pi_1 (p) = F_1^{-1}(p \cap \mathcal  V_1) \ \land \\ &\pi_2 (p) = F_2^{-1} (p \cap \mathcal V_2)\end{align}$

Extending this pair to an $\lambda$-tuple is immediate: $$(x_1,x_2,..)_\lambda = \bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda} F_\alpha (x_\alpha)$$

with Projections given by: $$\pi_\alpha (p) = F^{-1}_\alpha(p \cap \mathcal V_\alpha )$$

To extend it to proper classes, we need to upgrade the $F_\alpha$ bijections to:

$ F_\alpha: \mathcal P(V) \to \mathcal P^+(\mathcal V_\alpha)$

Where $\mathcal P^+(X)$ is the class of all nonempty subclasses of $X$.

This is a simple general way of having type-level ordered pairs\tuples, it works under lack of Extensionality, unlike Quine-Rosser type-level pairs which suffocate by existence of any Ur-element (atom).

However, this pair\tuple does require that $|A| \leq |P^+(V)|$; where $A$ is the class of all Atoms, which is there in $\sf ZFA$, but not fulfilled by any of the known models of $\sf NFU$. If $\sf NF$ proves to be consistent, then this would be equivalent to having as many Atoms as Sets, and so having those pairs would interpret $\sf NF$.

It appears to me that this is so simple that it must have been pondered before, hence my question is about reference to this particular way of defining ordered pairs\tuples.

> Had those tuples been worked up before? References?